# Django Template getting apparent catchall error: "AssertionError at / No exception message supplied"

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templating

I'm getting an error I believe to be secondary damage, or else a catchall error when the real error has not been pinpointed. (N.B. One search result for the error message said to make sure your tags have correct syntax; no `{# ... %}`. I double-checked, and I didn't notice any failures of properly nesting, opening, and closing tags.

The code that Django's 500 page is highlighting is:

```
5               <table>
6                   {% for pet in pets %}
7                       {% if not pet.should_hide %}
8                           <tr>
9                               <th valign="top">
10                                  <a href="/pet/{{ pet.slugline }}"
11                                    ><img src="{{ pet.main_image }}" /></a>
12                              </th>
13                              <td valign="top">
14                                  <h2>
15                                  {% if pet.slugline %}
16                                      <a href="/pet/{{ pet.slugline }}">
17                                  {% endif pet.slugline %}
18                                  {% if pet.name %}
19                                      {{ pet.name }}
20                                  {% else %}
21                                      Anonymous
22                                  {% endif %}
23                                  {% if pet.breed_or_type %}
24                                      - <span class="breed-or-type"
25                                        >{{ pet.breed_or_type }}</span>
```

The line that is labeled as causing the problem is 15, `{% if pet.slugline %}`. This is after lines 9-10, which include a pripr `{% if pet.slugline %}` as well as `{{ pet.slugline }}%`.

The whole template is at http://pastebin.com/EQMA9jyU [*base template available on request*].

Where should I be looking for the problem? Have I overlooked a mistake I made in Django templating, or is this secondary damage from problems elsewhere? (N.B. this is a work-in-progress; its functionality at the time of this posting is sub-MVP.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you simply try `{% endif %}` instead of  `{% endif pet.slugline %}`?